# Why am I unable to zoom my UIImageView embedded in a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I literally have the most basic of code and I'm so frazzled as to why it won't zoom:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, CGRectGetWidth([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds), CGRectGetHeight([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds))];
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.bounds.size;
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5;
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10.0;

    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];

    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"community1.jpeg"]];
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];
}
```

In the simulator I try to zoom and nothing at all happens. It's a rather large image if that's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you implement `-viewForZoomingInScrollView:` in your scroll view's delegate? If not, you need to do that, returning the view you want to actually zoom when you pinch.